# How to get all attribute names from selected XML node in C#

Tags: c#, xml, tags, xmlreader

This is my XML file. I need to select one test element and get all attributes name from its result child nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<summary>
  <test>
    <id>test 1</id>   
    <result value="-45">330</result>
    <result value="0">300</result>
    <result value="45">340</result>
  </test>
  <test>
    <id>test 3</id>    
    <result value="-45">330</result>
    <result value="0">300</result>
    <result value="45">340</result>
  </test>
</summary>
```

I wrote below code. but repeat same values and I want to stop it.

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(_xmlFilePath);

XmlNodeList nodelist = xd.GetElementsByTagName("result");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
    {
        string attrVal = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(attrVal);
    }
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can u show what is expected value of `nodelist` and output of `attrVal`

Comment: Output should be -45,0,45

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to Xml with `XDocument` class

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(_xmlFilePath);

var distinctResults = doc.Descendants("result")
                         .Select(element => element.Attribute("value").Value)
                         .Distinct();

foreach(var result in distinctResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Or with using of `HashSet<string>`

```
var results = doc.Descendants("result")
                 .Select(element => element.Attribute("value").Value);

var distinctResults = new HashSet<string>(results); 

foreach(var result in distinctResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Descendants' and no extension method 'Descendants' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' could be found

Comment: Use [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead of `XmlDocument`

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            string id = "test 1";

            var results = doc.Descendants("test").Where(x => (string)x.Element("id") == id).FirstOrDefault().Elements("result").Select(x => new
            {
                angle = (int)x.Attribute("value"),
                length = (int)x
            }).ToList();

        }


    }


}
```